# How to optimise SQL query consuming high CPU resources

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database-connection, azure-sql-database

I am using LINQ and MVC6 platform and hosted on the Microsoft Azure cloud. The following query is consuming high CPU resources.
Here is the query in SQL format

```
(@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000))SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[DevNews] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[AdminCheck]) AND ([Extent1].[Tags] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~') AND ([Extent1].[NewsLabels] IS NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Source] IN (N'PTI',N'IANS',N'Reuters'))
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: Any indexes? Actual execution plan?

Answer (score 3):

If there are Indexes suggested in query execution plan, create them for helping sql to scan large tables faster and better.
If no, then use a resource governor using SSRS to limit the resource for your login then run your query (this will reduce execution performance)

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion  ..  looking to your sample  you could avoid the subquery   and unuseful  () around each where condition

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[DevNews] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[AdminCheck] 
    AND [Extent1].[Tags] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~' 
    AND [Extent1].[NewsLabels] IS NULL
    AND [Extent1].[Source] IN (N'PTI',N'IANS',N'Reuters')
```

this should avoid the build of a temp table related  to the subquery

Comment: . . SQL Server does not materialize subqueries (as a general rule), so rewriting the query has no affect on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You query is essentially:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[DevNews] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[AdminCheck] AND 
     [Extent1].[Tags] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~' AND
     [Extent1].[NewsLabels] IS NULL AND
     [Extent1].[Source] IN (N'PTI', N'IANS', N'Reuters')
```

Removing the subquery should have no impact on performance in SQL Server.  However, an index will.  I would recommend a covering index with the following columns:  `(AdminCheck, NewsLabels, Source, Tags)`.

You need to be sure that `Source` is stored as `NCHAR` or `NVARChAR`.  Type conversion can slow the query.

Finally, a column called `Tags` is suspicious.  If this is a list of tags stored as a string, then you should revisit your data structure.  That is not the best way to store lists in SQL.